# storing the ids using map function does not go null after deleting all datas

Tags: reactjs

I'm storing all the ids in 'savedjobsIds' using map function and i check that with 'includes' in react. but i'm not able to get the 'savedjobsIds' null if i remove all the datas in firebase. the last id stays available. how to remove that. can some one help?
Following is the code

```
    const { joblists } = this.props
    const { savedjobs } = this.props
    const savedjobsIds = savedjobs && savedjobs.map(app => app.id)

<i id='heart' className={savedjobsIds.includes(joblist.id) ? 
"fas fa-heart float-right pr-4 text-danger" : 
"far fa-heart float-right pr-4 text-primary del"} 
name={joblist.id} onClick={this.saveJob1}></i>
```

below is the editable code i made
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vyx0kyvnq3

Comment: please provide more code or similar mock data...

Answer (score 0):

**You have not shown the code where you are deleting savedjobs array.**

**What is value of array savedjobs when passed as prop.?**

I am assuming, when delete call is made, it returns the deleted array, you are storing that and passing to the component. You just need to empty the array when you delete all items from array by using `savedjobs = []` before passing it as props.

Comment: `````this.props.removeSavedJobs(this.state)```` this is how i call the delete function. and use firesoter delete() to delete that particular data.

Comment: Will be needing a reproducible code to be able to help you out may be codesandbox link.